# Reverse Commands Which Disabled Network-Manager?

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, surface

While attempting a wifi fix, I was prompted to run the following commands:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/network-manager.conf /etc/init/network-manager.conf-disabled
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop.disabled
```

How can I reverse/undo those commands?

I ask because I could not get the wifi-fix to work, but am now unable to revert to an old workaround. I suspect this is because of changes made by those two commands. And so until I get this resolved, I cannot connect to the internet in Ubuntu, which is my primary OS.

Note that my netbook has no ethernet port, therefore I have no way of connecting to the internet in order to restore Network Manager, as has bee suggested to others facing Network Manager issues.

The fix I was attempting is detailed at this link:

[Marvell's wireless driver not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257600/marvells-wireless-driver-not-recognized/271093#271093)

Comment: Maybe a few words of explanation: "sudo" lets you run a command as a different user, usually root (required here, for files in /etc are usually system configuration files owned by root). "mv" moves a file to a different name/folder. "mv A B" renames file A to B, or if B is a directory, it moves file A to B/ and keeps the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they both should theoretically be root owned to begin with it should be as simple as:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/network-manager.conf-disabled /etc/init/network-manager.conf 
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop.disabled /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
```

If they have unexpected permissions, you will have to reverse that too and accept over-writes.

Comment: Afaik permissions should be preserved when copying/moving files as root.

Comment: That's possible, I'm just trying to see all possible problems coming instead of having an oh crap moment.

Comment: I'd do the same.

Comment: NP...we try...hard.  Just remember we helped you.